# JS import module and run on page load

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I want to call my function main() using html onload event and console.log text imported from another (generateObject.js) file, but when I import function, onload event stop working and function main() is not anymore used.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body onload="main()">
  </body>
</html>
```

generateObject.js:

```
export function hello() {
    return "Hello";
}
```

main.js:

```
import { hello } from './generateObject.js';
function main(){
      console.log(hello());
}

main();
```

When I try `console.log("text")` in `main()` it works but when I try to use imported function it's not.
What should I do to fix that?

Errors in Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (main.js:1)

index.html:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: main is not defined at onload (index.html:8)
```

Comment: are you calling the function in your main.js file? At the end of the file in main.js do this `main()`

Comment: but I want to call it on page load and in html body I have: onload="main()"

Comment: provide a working code snippet as what you have tried. it would be difficult to comment without knowing the context.

Comment: ok, I edited the post, added html code and chrome errors

Comment: I have answered your question. check to see if it solves your problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

modules will have its own scope. They are not available in the global scope like the normal scripts. So it's accessible only inside `main.js` in your case.

To make it work you need to add it to global scope explicitly.

```
import { hello } from './generateObject.js';
function main(){
      console.log(hello());
}

window.main = main;
```

Alternatively, you can remove the event handler from HTML and add it in the JS file.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import { hello } from './generateObject.js';
function main(){
      console.log(hello());
} 

window.addEventListener('load', main)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used  window.addEventListener('load', main)  and secound error is fixed, but first (Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (main.js:1)) is still there, have you any idea what is wrong?

Comment: change the main.js reference to `<script  type="module" src="main.js"></script>`

Comment: :D it brings two others problems in chrome:

Access to script at 'file:///D:/Programming/.Playground/gameInJS/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. 

 and 

 GET file:///D:/Programming/.Playground/gameInJS/main.js net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: This is a CROS error. you would have to run a server. Follow this to create a server `https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp` or install an npm package like `http-server`

Answer (score 1):

### generateObject.js:

```
export function hello() {
    return "Hello";
}
```

### main.js:

```
import { hello } from './generateObject.js';
function main(){
      console.log(hello());
} 

main();
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-sun-nry7d)

Comment: Unfortunately its not help :/

Comment: Hm. Try to use ```window.onload```. Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-cdn-b686p

Comment: I gather examples are working cause they use Parcel (looks default on codesandbox.io) and as a nota bene says under [https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html#-getting-started](http://web.archive.org/web/20200609063345/https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html) : "Parcel converts JS assets to ES5, which won't run in in the context of a `<script type="module">` tag, so just use plain `<script>` tags with no `type` attribute in your source HTML." And though I fail to inspect the 299 kB minified source, I'm sure it's just that replacement using "ES5" instead of `import` that makes it all work.

Answer (score 0):

You should add at the end of main.js a call to the main function. Try writing `main();` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Unfortunately its not working, still same errors in chrome console :/