# const elements defined in js module - cant access as DOM content not loaded yet

Tags: javascript

Using the below example. The const element `test_el` is null because the DOM content isn't loaded yet. So `test()` raises an error.

Wrapping the const definition in a onload event doesn't seem to work as its now now in the same scope as the function.

Whats the correct method of achieveing this - I know I can add the const within the function but it needs to be reused over multiple functions (not in this example)

main.js

```
import {test} from "../import.js" 
window.addEventListner("load", ()=>{
   test()
})
```

import.js

```
const test_el = document.getElementById("test_div")

export function test(){
    console.log(test_el.innerText)
}
```

Comment: try `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
 test()
});` instead of load event

Comment: doesn't work as the import happens first

Comment: so maybe it's some script after loading that appends your desired element.. in that case you can try waiting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS import module and run on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61047908/js-import-module-and-run-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1):

```js
// you can call
// all the tests that are dependent of `test_el` from one parent function
// after getting value of `test_el`

export function runTests() {
  const test_el = document.getElementById("test_div");
  if(test_el) {
   firstTest(test_el)
   secondTest(test_el)
 } else {
   throw new Error('Element not found.')
 }
}

function firstTest(element){
    assert(element.innerText.equal('someText'))
}

function secondTest(element){
    assert(element.classList.includes('someClass'))
}
```

Comment: in my question I say that I need to reuse the const over multiple functions

Comment: @LewisMorris My bad for not paying much attention. Just updated the answer.

Comment: Although it works, is passing the variable to each function the correct way to do it. Seems a bit counter intuitive. Will get me by for the moment though, cheers.